# Oracle ORDER BY in UNION

Tags: oracle

I have this query:

```
SELECT p.prenume||' '||p.nume ||' '||LOWER(REVERSE(c.titlu_curs)) AS "Info"
from profesori p JOIN didactic d ON d.id_prof = p.id_prof 
JOIN cursuri c ON d.id_curs = c.id_curs 
UNION
SELECT p.prenume||' '||p.nume||' ' AS "Info" from profesori p 
JOIN didactic d ON p.id_prof NOT IN 
(SELECT id_prof from didactic)
JOIN cursuri c ON c.id_curs NOT IN (SELECT id_curs from didactic) ORDER BY p.nume
```

How can I ORDER BY p.nume ? I get this error 'P"."NUME": invalid identifier'
I know I can order by Alias "Info" , but how can I order only by p.nume ?

Comment: try SELECT * FROM (your query) ORDER BY Info

Comment: I get the same error .

Comment: select also p.nume as "Nume" in your query execute in sql*plus (or any other program) the query and check how Oracle is naming the column, then add the order by.

Comment: I can't do that , its for a task . I need to select only 'p.prenume||' '||p.nume ||' '||LOWER(REVERSE(c.titlu_curs))' . I can't select p.nume too .. this is the problem

Comment: mm then maybe the task is rewriting the query without using an union, the fact you're unioning the very same table kind of makes me think about this. Can you add more details about what you're trying to do ? Just looking at this code, makes me think an OUTER JOIN would actually give the very same results without the need of an union.

Comment: Thanks man , OUTER JOIN was the solution .

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle. Corrected the tags.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I ORDER BY p.nume ?

With UNION queries we can only order by named columns in the projection of the first subquery. Your query only has `nume` as a part of a concatenated column, hence the ORA-00904 error.

Sorting the UNION query by the columns in the result set means you can sort by your column alias...

```
order by "Info"
```

...which means it will effectively sort by `prenume, nume, LOWER(REVERSE(c.titlu_curs))`.

The alternative solution - useful when you're not aliasing the sorting column - is to use the positional  notation

```
order by 1
```

Comment: Alternatively, `order by 1` would also work (meaning "sort by the first column" (which is "Info"). Though, that's probably not the best idea because people add columns and remove them, so "1" doesn't have to be the same column as it once was. I'd suggest `order by "Info"`.